# Angular2 animate when model changes

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-animation

I have component `PageComponent` which data is renewed on different url. I want animate when `Page` model is changed. In my given sample animation works only first time when `PageComponent` is loaded.

What should I add / change that animation would work when model is updated?

**page.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-page',
    templateUrl: './page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss'],
    providers: [PageService],
    pipes: [SafePipe],
    host: { '[@routeAnimation]': 'true' },
    animations: Animations.page
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

    page: Page;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private pageService: PageService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let uri = params['uri'];
            this.getPage(uri);
        });
    }

    getPage(uri: string) {
        this.pageService.getPage(uri).subscribe(
            page => this.page = page,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
    }
}
```

**animation.ts**

```
import {style, animate, transition, state, trigger} from '@angular/core';

export class Animations {
    static page = [
        trigger('routeAnimation', [
            transition('void => *', [
                style({
                    opacity: 0,
                    transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
                }),
                animate('2s ease-in')
            ]),
            transition('* => void', [
                animate('2s 10 ease-out', style({
                    opacity: 0,
                    transform: 'translateX(100%)'
                }))
            ])
        ])
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it using steps described in the article [Using ChangeDetection With Animation To Setup Dynamic Void Transitions In Angular 2 RC 6](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3140-using-changedetection-with-animation-to-setup-dynamic-void-transitions-in-angular-2-rc-6.htm). There are basically 3 steps you need to do:

1. Import **ChangeDetectorRef** class

   ```
   import { ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
   ```
2. Create instance of this class using dependency injection

   ```
   constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
   ```
3. Call method **detectChanges()** on your instance of the **ChangeDetectorRef** class after the change

   ```
   // Change your model ...
   SomeMethodWhichChangesTheModel();

   // ... and call the detectChanges() method on the ChangeDetectorRef
   this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
   ```